# Recursive diff and symlinks

Tags: bash, unix, diff

I'm trying to diff two directories using (well) `diff`. However, `diff` actually follows symlinks and compares differences between the targeted files. I can't seem to find a way to not have `diff` do this. Instead, what I would like to know is whether the targets are the same (or different for that matter). In other words, if the symlinks point to the same file, (in my opinion) they are the same, else they are different and that is all I want `diff` to tell me when it comes across symlinks during a recursive call.

I've tried looking online but I either find topics relating to dealing with symlinks alone or ignoring them altogether.

Answer (score 6):

GNU diff v3.3 introduce option `--no-dereference` that does the trick. This option is described by `diff --help` but not mentioned on the man page.

(see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/32026096/301717 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151837/72654)

Answer (score 1):

If you add lines like:

```
dir1/synlinkyfile.txt
config.mk
```

to a file `.ignore-diff`

then you can execute `diff(1)` like this:

```
diff -ur -X .ignore-diff
```

What I would suggest is to create a file of the ignores

```
find . -type l -exec stat '{}' '+' | grep 'File:' | sort | sed "s/^  File: \`//" | sed s/\'.*// >.ignore-diff
```

finds all symlinks in subdirectories, get the relevant line(s), sorts them(i like alphabetical things) and boils it down to a plain simple file path for the files that are actually symlinks. it finishes redirecting into .ignore-diff

of course, there is also the possibility of doing the .ignore and then doing that same search again, but taking off the last sed, and add a few more seds to take out all but the destinations.

```
find . -type l -exec stat '{}' '+' | grep 'File:' | sort | sed "s/^  File: \`//" | sed "s/.*-> \`//" | sed "s/'//g" | sed s/\`// > symlinks-dest
```

do that for each dir and then you could diff those two symlinks-dest files to compare the symlink destinations.

Comment: Thanks PsychoData. Seems to be a reasonable solution (in theory).

Comment: Not sure how long find will take to execute on a directory as large as mine though.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with running diff using an 'ignore' file. After playing around with what you suggested, it turns out that adding something like <dir>/<file> to .ignore-diff doesn't work. Adding just <file> however does work. This is a problem. What if I have a file called <file> in a different sub directory somewhere which I don't want ignored?